# Which case is used to check Drift and P-delta for a building subject to seismic forces?

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, design, structural-analysis

Which case is used to check the drift and P-delta for a building according to ASCE ?

- Static lateral force procedure (with a period Comparing T the real fundamental period with CuTa)
- Static lateral force procedure (without comparing T with CuTa)
- Modal response spectrum analysis (without scaling)
- Modal response spectrum analysis (with scaling)

Comment: Do you have an endless supply of questions?

Comment: I am a student doing a project that is why all the questions sorry

Comment: If you explained that as part of your questions, then it may help the responses you receive.